# External hard drive load takes forever on Nautilus/Gparted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, nautilus, gparted

I believe I damaged my hard drive by doing some dumb things while moving some files, I'm trying to find out if it's bricked or if I can still recover it.

When I try to access the eHDD using Nautilus, I'm able to access the root folders inside the drive (the eHDD is recognized and it shows as "1.0TB Volume") but as soon as I try to change directory it takes forever to load, sometimes it shows the contents and other times it doesn't, just keeps loading.

I tried to open [gparted](https://gparted.org/) so I could format the HDD, but it takes forever while showing "scanning all devices". If I remove the eHDD, then gparted shows an error (something along "error while reading /dev/sda1") and it loads normally, which means that it was the external hard drive that was causing trouble.

The hard drive folders are organized as follows:

```
\ (root)
.
+-- backup/
|   +-- lots-of-folders/
|
+-- new_pc/
    +-- code/
```

I can see both the `backup` and `new_pc` normally, but as soon as I do `cd backup` on terminal, the command hangs and loads forever, even if I send a SIGKILL signal with `Ctrl+C`.

I believe that what broke the eHDD was that I was moving some big files (13 Gb approx) to both `backup` and `new_pc` folders. Since the command was taking hours to complete, I tried to cancel it using SIGKILL. Then the command hung completely and because I was impatient, I just pulled the USB cable from the computer, which I believe left the HDD in an invalid state.

**Given the circumstances, can I still recover the eHDD or is it completely bricked?**

I don't mind if I lose the data and I believe that maybe I could format the HDD from the terminal, but I'm not familiar with filesystems/partitioning commands in Linux yet, that's why I tried to use gparted as I'm more comfortable with it.

Comment: I'm not actually. I have pretty much all the data on my personal computer. The external hard drive was a backup. I just need it to be usable so I can transfer files from an old computer to a new one.

Comment: First, may I ask you to connect the eHDD and run `sudo parted -l` , then click [edit] back here and paste the result into the bottom of your question? Secondly, try using the GNOME Disk Utility to see if the eHDD is recognized and if you can delete the eHDD partition and create a new one then format it. https://linuxhint.com/gnome_disk_utility/ https://packages.debian.org/stretch/admin/gnome-disk-utility

Comment: I just managed to get it working again. I did exactly what you suggested. Since GNOME Disk was the only program that was recognizing it, I used it to format the partition. After a really long time, it managed to get the eHDD without any partition. Then gparted was able to read it. So I used it to create a new partition table and a new ext4 partition on it. Now I'm not sure if I should erase the question or answer it.

Comment: Answer it, mi amigo; get the XP from the points for answering your own question, go slay another monster. Also suggest going to website of HDD maker and looking for diagnostic apps they may have, esp. SMART apps; it not, run it through smartctl to see it there's anything lurking within. Maybe remove the eHDD from the shell and put it inside the desktop (ignore that if you have a laptop).I've found GNOME Disk Utility has fixed quite a few things which parted could not, including reviving borked USB flash drives, so glad it worked again. BTW, what did `sudo parted -l` show?

Comment: I didn't run `sudo parted -l` before formatting. I didn't run it after formatting because I wasn't expecting to get the same results. But after using it for a while, it started showing the same problems again. I can't even create a folder. I'll run `smartctl` and `sudo parted -l` once I have free time and maybe add their output as an edit.